# Spark Spark Empty Json Files reading from Directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm reading from a path say /json/*/myfiles_*.json

I'm then flattening the json using explode. This causes an error since I have some empty files. How do I tell it to ignore empty files of somehow filter them out?

I can detect individual files checking if the head is empty but I need to do this on the collection of files iterated in the dataframe with the use of the wildcard path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer seems to be that I need to provide a schema explicitly because it can't infer one from empty file - as you would expect!

e.g.

```
val schemadf = sqlContext.read.json(schemapath) //infer schema from file with data or do manually
val schema = schemadf.schema
val raw = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(monthfile)

val prep = raw.withColumn("MyArray", explode($"MyArray"))
  .select($"ID", $"name", $"CreatedAt")

display(prep)
```